# WordPress Custom Query WHERE?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to query some data onto my page on WordPress, but I am not sure where to actually put my SQL function. It has been driving me crazy for 2 days and have not found out an answer. I've look through my phpadmin, wp-db.php .. Am I missing something here? Could somebody please post the very first steps on getting this started..? I have experience in writing code and SQL, so if I just know where to put my code in I could get started. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with tis. Are you trying to write query to on theme or backend ?

Comment: I am looking at my FileManager right now,  WHERE oh where would I put my code in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordPress Query to fetch data from your database . Instead of writing SQL query, you can fetch from $wpdb . query_posts() or WP_Query() are the predefined functions in WordPress . For fetching all pages, you can just use : `query_posts('post_type=page');` similarlly posts `query_posts('post_type=post');`

Other conditions can be specified in the args section , ie for particular page name :

```
query_posts('post_type=page&post_name=contact');
```

Thank You

Comment: thank you for your help  but where would i put this sort of code in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example query:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$querystr = "
SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb-
>term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb-
>term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb-
>term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wpostmeta.meta_key = 'customDateField'
AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= CURDATE()
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN(1,2)
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC
LIMIT 4
";
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help  but where would i put this sort of code in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Use WP_QUERY class for your queries. You can write the code in template files of your theme.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );
```

Here you will find examples and documentation.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

for custom queries use wpdb class:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

```
// 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );

// 2nd Method - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal. Does not require global keyword ( but may not be best practice )

$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```